# Emgu CV smile detection

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am doing a project that takes a photo when you smile, but I am not doing smile detection *per se*.

(My project is taking a photo when you smile)

How do I do smile detection so that I can take the photo?

This is my project source code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Capture capture;        
    private bool captureInProgress;
    private HaarCascade haar;
    private HaarCascade mouth;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        haar = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
        mouth = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml");

    }
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();

        if (ImageFrame !=null)
        {
            Image<Gray, byte> grayFrame = ImageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
            Image<Gray, Byte> gray = ImageFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
            var faces = grayFrame.DetectHaarCascade(haar, 1.4, 4, HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(25, 25))[0];
            foreach (var face in faces)
            {
                ImageFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);

                MCvAvgComp[][] mouthsDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(mouth, 1.1, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
                gray.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                foreach (MCvAvgComp e in mouthsDetected[0])
                {
                    Rectangle mouthRect = e.rect;
                    mouthRect.Offset(face.rect.X, face.rect.Y);
                    ImageFrame.Draw(mouthRect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                }
            }

        }

        CamImageBox.Image = ImageFrame;       

    }

    private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region if capture is not created, create it now
        if (capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        if (capture != null)
        {
            if (captureInProgress)
            {  //if camera is getting frames then stop the capture and set button Text
                // "Start" for resuming capture
                btnStart.Text = "Başlat"; //
                Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
            }
            else
            {
                //if camera is NOT getting frames then start the capture and set button
                // Text to "Stop" for pausing capture
                btnStart.Text = "Durdur";
                Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
            }

            captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
        }
    }
    private void ReleaseData()
    {
        if (capture != null)
            capture.Dispose();
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about viewing the respective Image, from your processing,

Emgu CV recommends the use of [ImageBox](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/ImageBox) control for display purpose, for the following reasons. This can be used in conjunction with the ImageFrame (Image) object you have in your above code sample.

ImageBox is a high performance control for displaying image. Whenever possible, it displays a Bitmap that shares memory with the Image object, therefore no memory copy is needed (very fast).

The user will be able to examine the image pixel values, video frame rates, color types when the image is being displayed.

It is convenient to perform simple image operations with just a few mouse clicks.

**Converting to Bitmap**

The Image class has a **ToBitmap()** function that return a Bitmap object, which can easily be displayed on a PictureBox control using Windows Form.

**Detecting a Mouth/Smile**

You will want to provide a Haarcascade XML for the mouth, and capture accordingly. See the below [code](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4184), which can draw a rectangle around the mouth,

```
CascadeClassifier mouth = new CascadeClassifier(Application.StartupPath + "/haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml");
Image<Bgr, Byte> currentframe= null;
Image<Gray, byte> grayFrame = null;
Capture grabber = new Capture();

currentframe = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(500, 320, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

            if (currentframe != null)
            {
                grayFrame = currentframe.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

                Rectangle[] mouthDetected = mouth.DetectMultiScale(grayFrame, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);

                // to draw rectangle 
                foreach (Rectangle mouthFound in mouthDetected)
                {
                   ...
                }
            }
```